# How can I get a YACC-type parser to stop on the shortest matching input?

Tags: parsing, stream, grammar, yacc, ply

Here's the context:  I have a file (or stream), and I want to process its header, stop, and then deal with the rest of the data differently.  That is, suppose I have a stream like `BEGIN GOOD GOOD GOOD GOOD GOOD DONE JUNK JUNK JUNK JUNK ...`.  The first part (`BEGIN GOOD+ DONE`) matches my grammar, and I want to stop as soon as I see `DONE`.

AFAIK, YACC and friends want to keep consuming tokens until there are no more, so I have to write more grammar to match all the `JUNK`.  Is there a way around this?

I'm using PLY (a Lex and Yacc implementation for Python), but I'm open to general answers here.

Comment: As an aside, I ended up punting on doing this with PLY (or YACC) and went with ANTLR, where this behavior seems to be the default.  Which is not necessarily better, but it fit the bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal yacc, you can use the yacc macro `YYACCEPT` in an action to immediately return a successful parse without reading any more tokens.  I don't know if PLY supports that, however.